# ImportError: no module named sounddevice

Tags: python, audio, module, pyaudio, portaudio

Currently trying to use sounddevice in some code I am writing, but I keep getting the error mentioned in the title.
So far, I have tried installed sounddevice in all python versions I have, uninstalled and reinstalled it a few times, added this to the top of the code:

```
'#!/usr/bin/env python3'
```

Also, I have tried reinstalling rtmidi-python, pyaudio, cffi, and sounddevice all at once and each individually

I also have ran the pip freeze command and I get these results, which are some of the modules I am looking to try to install, and am having issue with all:

```
'cffi==1.14.2
PyAudio==0.2.11
sounddevice==0.4.0'
```

To my knowledge, PyAudio is a Python version of PortAudio (which is only for C++ and C), so in order to use PortAudio/PyAudio needs to be installed to use sounddevice.
Sidenote: Not sure if it is related, but I also keep getting told to upgrade pip, but I do have the most up to date version, and keep getting this error when installing something:

```
`Error initializing entry point('gnome','keyrings.alt.Gnome',None,Distribution('keyrings.alt','3.4.0'))`
```

Please let me know what else I can try to get this to work, I am still a beginner and am not quite sure how some of this works. Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you do `python3 -m pip install sounddevice --user && python3 -c 'import sounddevice'`?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have not tried that before, closest thing to that that I have seen so far is to "python3 -m pip install sounddevice" minus the "--user". I will give that a shot.

Comment: @Matthias Alright, I tried the command out. The first attempt returned an error saying it could not run --user commands while inside the virtual environment, which lead the the second attempt. When running it the second time, it says the requirements are already satisfied within the ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages location and gives the version as 0.4.0. It also gives that EntryPoint('gnome') error again.

Comment: OK, what if you start with a fresh virtual environment and do `python3 -m pip install pip --upgrade && python3 -m pip install sounddevice && python3 -c 'import sounddevice'`?

Comment: @Matthias The second attempt was done outside the virtual environment, I should have clarified. By "fresh", do you mean launching the virtual environment and then immediately running that command? If so, that is what I tried on the first attempt.

Comment: @Matthias Whoops, was moving a bit fast, didn't recognize that that command is a little different than the one before. I will try that instead.

Comment: @Matthias Alright, I tried that command and good news! It installed correctly, I then was able to install soundfile as well, which was also needed, and that installed flawlessly! Only issue now is the code! Thanks a whole lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with the sounddevice lib:
I created a new virtual env in pycharm and installed sounddevice via pip. In the IDE everything worked fine but when i used pyinstaller to build and executable, i got an import error on startup. What helped me was deinstalling sounddevice with pip, updating/reinstalling pip and installing it again, similar to the comments under the original post.
Maybe this will help someone else :)